# What are some examples of multiplicative quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, conservation-laws

Wikipedia does not have much on its page for [multiplicative quantum numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_quantum_number), so I was wondering if there was a list or something somewhere?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246152/84967

Comment: It's worth scoping what physics you accept for the purposes of this question. Whether [this counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity) depends on whether it exists. You'll find that happens with some examples.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplicative quantum numbers arise as eigenvalues of finite transformations, where additive ones occurs as a result of infinitesimal transformations.

Thus, parity is multiplicative since parity is a finite transformations.  Similarly, if a state $\vert\psi\rangle$ is even under permutation and $\vert\chi\rangle$ is odd under permutation of its constituents, then
$\vert\psi\rangle\vert\chi\rangle$ is odd.

On the other hand, the eigenvalues of $\hat L_z$ are additive since $\hat L_z$ is a generator of infinitesimal transformations.  Thus, for small $\theta$:
\begin{align}
\exp^{-i\theta (\hat L_z^{(1)}+\hat L_z^{(2)})}\vert \ell_1m_1\rangle \vert \ell_2m_2\rangle&\approx 
\left(\hat 1 -i\theta (\hat L_z^{(1)}+\hat L_z^{(2)})+\ldots\right)\vert \ell_1m_1\rangle \vert \ell_2m_2\rangle\, , \\
&= \left(\hat 1 -i\theta (m_1+m_2)\right)\vert \ell_1m_1\rangle \vert \ell_2m_2\rangle
\end{align}